# Align table td horizontal in blade

Tags: html, laravel, html-table, laravel-blade

I am trying to make school attendance now in my view, is there a way that I could align the **Days and Status** horizontally without repeating the student name:

[image]

**Here is my blade view:**

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th>Student</th>
        <th>Days</th>
        <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach($atnd as $atnds)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$atnds->lead->student_name}}</td>
        <td>{{$atnds->days}}</td>
        <td>{{$atnds->status}}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

**This is my controller**

```
public function get_attendance(){
    $atnd = Attendance::with(['level','lead'])->where(['level_id'=> 11])->get();
    return view('attendance.index',compact('atnd'));
}
```

Comment: Means you don't want to repeat the student name if is the same as last one?

Comment: Mean of align is order by ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is group by student_id after `->get()` it will give you collection of collection and then show the dates and Student Name in header (Assuming you have dates same for all student) like this

In Controller

```
$atnds=Attendance::with(['level','lead'])->where(['level_id'=> 11])->get()->groupBy('student_id');
```

In view

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th>Student</th>
        @foreach($atnds->first() as $row)
            <th>{{$row->days}}</th> //assuming you have dates same for all student
        @endforeach
    </tr>
    @foreach($atnds as $group)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $group->first()->lead->student_name}}</td>
            @foreach($group as $row)
                <td>{{$row->status}}</td>
            @endforeach
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

**Edit**

For date filter you can add `->whereMonth('days', '07')` condition

For showing dropdown in status you can add it like this (Replace $row->status)

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
    @if($atnds->count() > 0){
        <tr>
            <th>Student</th>
            @foreach($atnds->first() as $row)
                <th>{{$row->days}}</th>
            @endforeach
        </tr>
        @foreach($atnds as $studentId => $group)
            <tr>
                <td>
                   {{ $group->first()->lead->student_name}} 
                </td>
                @foreach($group as $index => $row)
                    <td>
                        <input type="hidden" name="student[{{ $studentId }}][{{ $index }}][day]" value = "{{ $row->days }}" />
                        <select name="student[{{ $studentId }}][{{ $index }}][status]">
                            <option {{ $row->status == 'P' ? 'selected' : '' }}  value = "P">P</option>
                            <option {{ $row->status == 'L' ? 'selected' : '' }}  value = "L">L</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                @endforeach
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    @else
        <tr><td>No Record</td></tr>
    @endif
</table>
```

Comment: can i have a follow up question sir , how can i replace the status as select box then perform update which target the same student id

Comment: What are the options for `status` do you want in `select` ?

Comment: i want to add [A, L] only sir if possible and by the way how to control the date result like from july1 to july 30 only